# Shared libraries and language standards

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

AFAIK, neither C99 nor C++ standards are aware of shared libraries. Why is that?

EDIT: What is a good practice of writing shared libs without duplicating Linux/Windows versions?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplicating Linux/Windows versions. But here's a good reference for how to manage exports: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons why this makes sense in 1999 (as in the case of C99) or even 2011:

- There are still systems where C and C++ are used that don't have shared libraries.  (Think embedded.)  If the standard mandated something, life is needlessly difficult for compiler/library implementers who are targetting platforms where the question of shared libraries is irrelevant.
- Different operating systems make different design choices with regard to shared libraries.  If the standard mandated something, it would limit those choices.  There is also a lot of icky legacy here to consider as shared library implementations have evolved over time.

As is the case with many things in C and C++, other, more platform-specific standards do a fine enough job here where the language itself has left things unspecified.  According to manpages I just looked up, POSIX.1-2001 specifies `dlopen` et al.  If you are targetting Windows you know where to find `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`.  `__declspec` requirements for Windows can also be wrapped in a macro.  If you care about both Windows and POSIXy systems it's not too hard to write a layer that does the appropriate thing.  I'm sure there are lots already written and available.

Comment: How about unofficial standard, similar to boost threads? Just curious.

Answer (score 6):

Because a shared library is a feature of the OS.

Nothing to do with any particular language.

Comment: But shared libs require syntax support. It would be nice if Linux and Windows used the same syntax.

Comment: @pic11: "shared libs require syntax support"?  Not really.  It's all just `externs` and tools.

Comment: @S.Lott. Shared libs are coded differently for Linux and Windows. Tools come later.

Comment: (The first shared lib system I've seen was AmigaOS.)

Comment: @pic11: Desktop apps and web apps are coded differently, too.  That doesn't change the **language**.  Just the way the language is applied to a problem.

Comment: @S.Lott. *Desktop apps and web apps are coded differently, too* That isn't the point. Say, I want code my own shared regex lib for Linux and Windows. Static lib version would work on almost every C++ platform (Win, Linux, iPhone, OSX, Desktop, Server) with almost zero change, as long as I stick to standard C++. But shared lib version won't, because Visual C++ and GCC use different syntax. I don't see why the syntax can't be the same. I am not saying that compiler & tools should be standardised.

Comment: @Pic11: You cant mix and match binaries from different compilers reliably anyway (technically you can't even mix and match binaries from the same compiler that have different flags set).

Answer (score 4):

["How to write shared libraries" by Ulrich Drepper](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), 
read the first page about them and their history.